# google load balancer + nginx + symfony2

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, symfony

i'm trying to configure a scalable symfony2 app, so i read this page https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example

i did every thing like they said, is working with a simple nginx conf :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
}
```

with that i get a positive check health and if i try http://ip_load_balancer i get the nginx's default page.

But when i try my real nginx's conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name myapp-public.com;
root /usr/share/nginx/html/app-public/web;


recursive_error_pages off;

error_log /var/log/nginx/app_error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/app_access.log;

location / {
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}

# PROD
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    internal;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
}
```

When i try http://ip_load_blancer, i get 502 Server Error.
But when i try http://ip_vm1, i get my application (i open the http access from all to test).

Also all the check health fail.
I don't really understand what's wrong, any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: On what port have you configured your health checks ?

Comment: i have configured port 80

Comment: Do you have a path configured for health check? If yes, can you try to replace the path with a static HTML page and see whether the health check is successful ?

Comment: I have the same issue and also getting 502. I can access the app with the IP of the instance but not with the load balancer frontend IP. (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/38052185/454103). Did you find a solution to your problem? (Other than moving to AWS)

Comment: Not yet. I will work on it again in 2 weeks so i will keep you inform.

Comment: It's now working. I need to document my solution then i will post the link.

Comment: @anthony it looks like you were able to resolve your issue. Is it possible to post the answer and accept it so other people can benefit from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment here is what i think was my problem @George

You need to keep in mind that if the check health failed, there will be no redirect to the specific instance.
==> So i create a default conf for my nginx (i add ssl in the conf)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}



server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name _;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/secure.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mysecure.key;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Second things, you have to accept traffic from your load balancer and health check from google to the instance's port 80 (and 443 in my case) cf.

==> https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/cross-region-example#shutting_off_https_access_from_everywhere_but_the_load_balancing_service

I hope this help you, if you want more details, or if you don't understand something, just tell me, i will try to explain more.

PS : Sorry for the wait